# Green's theorem application in Complex analysis

Tags: complex-analysis, greens-theorem

> Let $\phi\in C_c^{\infty}(\mathbb{C}).$ Prove that $\displaystyle \int_{|z-w|>\epsilon} \log|z-w|\Delta\phi(z)dA(z)=\int_0^{2\pi}(\phi(w+re^{it})-r\log r\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial r}(w+re^{it})|_{r=\epsilon}dt$ using Green's Theorem.

So, $\displaystyle \int_{|z-w|>\epsilon} \log|z-w|\Delta\phi(z)dA(z)=\displaystyle \int_{|z-w|>\epsilon} \phi \Delta\log|z-w|dA(z)$ by Greens Theorem and since $\phi$ has compact support. Then, again by Green's theorem, $\displaystyle \displaystyle \int_{|z-w|>\epsilon} \phi \Delta\log|z-w|dA(z)=\int_0^{2\pi} (\phi(w+re^{it}) \frac{\partial \log r}{\partial n})|_{r=\epsilon} dt$ where $\hat{n}$ is the unit inner normal vector to the circle $|z|=\epsilon$. Now, how do I proceed towards the final result? I am stuck here. Can somebody please help me?

Comment: Isn't the function $z\mapsto \log\, \lvert z - w\rvert$ harmonic on $\lvert z - w\rvert > \epsilon$, which would make $\int_{\lvert z - w\rvert > \epsilon} \phi \Delta \log\, \lvert z - w\rvert\, dA(z) = 0$? Also, is $\phi$ real-valued?

Comment: ya but the book in which I found this, proved then the $\lim_{\epsilon\rightarrow 0} \int_{|z-w|>\epsilon} \log|z-w|\Delta\phi(z)dA(z)=2\pi \phi(w)$ after having the equation shown in the above post.

Comment: It looks like you have to do an integration by parts to move the $d/dn = d/dr$ to $\phi$